# Angular Child binding and transclusion

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I would like to do some

```
<my-table-component [Items]="Items">
  <my-column-component Title="The Id">
    {{Item.Id}}
  </my-column-component>
  <my-column-component Title="The Name">
    <span>{{Item.Name}}</span>
  </my-column-component>
  <my-column-component Title="The Avatar">
    <img [src]="Item.Picture" />
  </my-column-component>
</my-table-component>
```

The issue is that I don't want the content of each column to be rendered right *here* and *right now*.

Giving the `Items` contains array of object like:

```
Items = [
  { Id: 1, Name: "I'm One", Picture: "/picture/1.jpg" },
  { Id: 2, Name: "I'm Two", Picture: "/picture/2.jpg" },
  { Id: 3, Name: "I'm Three", Picture: "/picture/3.jpg" },
]
```

The end result I want would be something like

```
<div class="my-table-component">
  <div class="my-table-component-header">
    <div class="my-table-component-header-item">The Id</div>
    <div class="my-table-component-header-item">The Name</div>
    <div class="my-table-component-header-item">The Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-table-component-content">
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item">1</div>
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><span>I'm One</span></div>
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><img [src]="/picture/1.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-table-component-content">
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item">2</div>
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><span>I'm Two</span></div>
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><img [src]="/picture/2.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-table-component-content">
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item">3</div>
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><span>I'm Three</span></div>
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><img [src]="/picture/3.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the binding of each column is not made directly here it is declared, but dynamicly, for each `Item` of the table component bound `Items`.

I've try things using [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet), but or I don't understand well how it works, or it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the issue? you want to use `ng-template`? or you want to have the end result?

Comment: I want to repeat each column component for each `Item` of `Items` in the table component.

Comment: See if this helps you, I will add as an answer... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfrrcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Frow%2Frow.component.ts

Comment: Same as @Horace Lee, I want to make columns/row fully dynamic.

Comment: Yeah... so they are. Isn't it dynamic.. see the updated stackBlitz..

Comment: It's not dynamic in the way that, the column `Name` & `Greeting` are hardcoded in your components.

Comment: So, you mean.. you don't know the keys of `Items`?? Keys are dynamic and hence the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177209/discussion-between-jbuiss0n-and-ashish-ranjan).

Comment: You go ahead with the `cdk` table you mentioned.. just adding a comment to let you know that the stackblitz has dynamic headers now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses structural directives and NgTemplateOutlet to achieve the result you want. See this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-transclusion-2) for the full code.

## Usage

**Starting HTML:**

(`app.component.html`)

```
<my-table-component [Items]="Items">
    <my-column-component>
        <my-cell *columnHeader>The Id</my-cell>
        <my-cell *columnCells="let Item">{{Item.Id}}</my-cell>
    </my-column-component>
    <my-column-component>
        <my-cell *columnHeader>The Name</my-cell>
        <my-cell *columnCells="let Item"><span>{{Item.Name}}</span></my-cell>
    </my-column-component>
    <my-column-component>
        <my-cell *columnHeader>The Avatar</my-cell>
        <my-cell *columnCells="let Item"><img src="{{Item.Picture}}" /></my-cell>
    </my-column-component>
</my-table-component>
```

Notes:

- Use the `*columnHeader` and `*columnCells` structural directives to denote which cells you want to become the column headers and regular table cells respectively
- To use data binding (e.g. `<span>{{Item.Name}}</span>`) in the table cells, set `*columnCells="let myVarHere"` (e.g. `*columnCells="let Item"`) to declare the iteration variable that you want to use.

---

**End result:**

```
<div class="my-table-component">
   <div class="my-table-component-header">
      <div class="my-table-component-header-item"><my-cell>The Id</my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-header-item"><my-cell>The Name</my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-header-item"><my-cell>The Avatar</my-cell></div>
   </div>
   <div class="my-table-component-content">
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell>1</my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell><span>I'm One</span></my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell><img src="/picture/1.jpg" /></my-cell></div>
   </div>
   <div class="my-table-component-content">
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell>2</my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell><span>I'm Two</span></my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell><img src="/picture/2.jpg" /></my-cell></div>
   </div>
   <div class="my-table-component-content">
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell>3</my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell><span>I'm Three</span></my-cell></div>
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item"><my-cell><img src="/picture/3.jpg" /></my-cell></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

**Angular code:**

(`app.component.ts`)

```
export class AppComponent {
  Items = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "I'm One", Picture: "/picture/1.jpg" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "I'm Two", Picture: "/picture/2.jpg" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "I'm Three", Picture: "/picture/3.jpg" },
  ];
}
```

(`my-table-components.component.ts` - I chose to put all the "table"-related components/directives in one file but you can split this into multiple files if you want)

```
import { Component, Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: 'my-column-component' })
class MyColumnComponent { }

@Directive({ selector: 'my-cell' })
class MyCell { }

@Component({
  selector: 'my-table-component',
  template: `
  <div class="my-table-component">
    <div class="my-table-component-header">
      <div class="my-table-component-header-item" *ngFor="let header of columnHeaders">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header; context: {$implicit:Item}"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="my-table-component-content" *ngFor="let Item of Items">
      <div class="my-table-component-content-item" *ngFor="let cell of columnCells">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cell; context: {$implicit: Item}"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
class MyTableComponent {
  @Input() Items: Object[];

  columnHeaders: TemplateRef<void>[] = [];
  columnCells: TemplateRef<void>[] = [];
}


// Structural directives

@Directive({ selector: '[columnHeader]'})
class ColumnHeader {
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<void>, table: MyTableComponent) {
    table.columnHeaders.push(templateRef);
  }
}

@Directive({ selector: '[columnCells]'})
class ColumnCell {
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<void>, table: MyTableComponent) {
    table.columnCells.push(templateRef);
  }
}


export { MyTableComponent, MyCell, MyColumnComponent, ColumnHeader, ColumnCell }
```

---

## Explanation

In the starting HTML, you have something like this to represent each column:

```
<my-column-component>
   <my-cell *columnHeader>The Id</my-cell>
   <my-cell *columnCells="let Item">{{Item.Id}}</my-cell>
</my-column-component>
```

Notice that we are putting an asterisk `*` prefix in front of the `columnHeader` and `columnCells` directives. This tells Angular that we want to use the directives as *structural directives*. (A structural directive is a directive that changes the DOM *structure*, such as by adding, removing, or manipulating elements. For example, `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` are structural directives.)

Internally, Angular de-sugarizes the asterisk syntax by wrapping an `<ng-template>` tag around the original element. For example, this:

```
<my-cell *columnHeader>The Id</my-cell>
<my-cell *columnCells="let Item">{{Item.Id}}</my-cell>
```

would be converted into this:

```
<ng-template columnHeader>
   <my-cell>The Id</my-cell>
</ng-template>
<ng-template columnCells let-Item>
   <my-cell>{{Item.Id}}</my-cell>
</ng-template>
```

So each element with the `*columnHeader` or `*columnCells` directive would be wrapped around with an `<ng-template>` element. Since they're each inside an `<ng-template>`, we can Angular's `TemplateRef` to get a reference to the `<ng-template>` element, and then pass the reference into `MyTableComponent` to be displayed using `*ngTemplateOutlet`.

Have a look at [this diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY6LN.png) to see what I mean.

Example:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[columnCells]'})
class ColumnCell {
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<void>, table: MyTableComponent) {
    table.columnCells.push(templateRef);
  }
}
```

--

```
<div class="my-table-component">
  <div class="my-table-component-header">
    <div class="my-table-component-header-item" *ngFor="let header of columnHeaders">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="header; context: {$implicit:Item}"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="my-table-component-content" *ngFor="let Item of Items">
    <div class="my-table-component-content-item" *ngFor="let cell of columnCells">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="cell; context: {$implicit: Item}"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I recommend taking a look at [this excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTwKhxLZ3jI) to get a better understanding of structural directives and NgTemplateOutlet, as well as the [code example](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#example) in the Angular docs for NgTemplateOutlet.